# Is it possible to cast an object to System.Windows.DataObject.DataStore.DataStoreEntry?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, casting

System.Windows.DataObject.DataStore.DataStoreEntry.  When I type that into my Visual Studio text editor.. I am told

> The type name 'DataStore' does not exist in the type 'System.Windows.DataObject'

However, when I debug in the Immediate Window, I have no problems whatsoever.

Even if I use the dynamic keyword in my code.. at run-time, it blows up when I access a field in it.. saying an 'object' has no Data field.. but it is a dynamic variable!! and I can put a breakpoint on the variable and clearly see the data field.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to MSDN (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.dataobject.aspx), there is no `DataStore` class exposed in the `System.Windows.DataObject` class.

Actually, looking in Reflector, the nested `DataStore` class does exist, but it's `private` - that's why you can see it in the debugger (i.e. immediate window) but can't use it in real code.

Comment: Ah, OK. I Ctrl+F'ed that same site and was saddened.. but what you say makes sense.  Should I be able use reflection to get at it anyways?

Comment: No - you can't use reflection since at the end you'll just end up with an `object`, so you haven't really accomplished anything.  The real question is what are you actually trying to accomplish with this hack?

Comment: I want to get the data associated with a DragEventArgs :S

Comment: Then yes, you can certainly use reflection to read property values from the object.